# Why Bitmap to Base64 String showing black background on webview in android?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-webview

I am using a code that combine to images into 1 by using canvas . I show that image to ImageView it looks fine. But when I try to show that into WebView it show background black to right that image. I try to change the background color in HTML but it not change color. or make transparent. Can anyone help? [Result is here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?f49304578b.png) The above image is in ImageView and below is in WebView.

```
public class MyBimapTest extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

    img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Drawable dra1 = img1.getDrawable();
    Bitmap map1 = ((BitmapDrawable) dra1).getBitmap();
    ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
    img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Drawable dra2 = img2.getDrawable();
    Bitmap map2 = ((BitmapDrawable) dra2).getBitmap();

    // ***
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    map1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String abc = Base64.encodeBytes(b);

    byte[] byt = null;
    try {
        byt = Base64.decode(abc);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    map1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byt, 0, byt.length);

    // ***
    Bitmap map = combineImages(map1, map2);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bbb = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    map.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bbb);

    byte[] bit = bbb.toByteArray();

    String imgToString = Base64.encodeBytes(bit);

    String imgTag = "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64," + imgToString
            + "' align='left' bgcolor='ff0000'/>";

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.storyView);
    webView.loadData(imgTag, "text/html", "utf-8");
    Drawable end = new BitmapDrawable(map);

    ImageView img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView03);
    img3.setImageBitmap(map);
}

public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) { 
    Bitmap cs = null;
    int width, height = 0;

    width = c.getWidth() + (s.getWidth() / 2);
    height = c.getHeight() + (s.getHeight() / 2);

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);

    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth() - (s.getWidth() / 2), c
            .getHeight()
            - (s.getHeight() / 2), null);
    return cs;
}
```

}

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `JPEG` format does not support alpha transparency, which is why the transparent background becomes black when you convert your original image to `JPEG`.

Use the `PNG` format instead:

```
 map1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
```

and

```
String imgTag = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + imgToString               
    + "' align='left' bgcolor='ff0000'/>";
```

Comment: Thanks so much...was using compression format JPEG before.
get more detail here
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html

Comment: Perfect answer till compress() however, Where to apply imgTag? Can you please help me?

Comment: @VVB: the two lines that I put in my answer are both modifications to the code that OP posted. In his code, look for the line `webView.loadData(imgTag, "text/html", "utf-8");` - this is the place where the tag gets added to the web page being built.