# how to improve image quality on Canvas.drawBitmap while merging two images?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-widget

I am using following code to merge 2 different bitmap into 1.

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) { 
Bitmap cs = null;
int width, height = 0;

width = c.getWidth() + (s.getWidth() / 2);
height = c.getHeight() + (s.getHeight() / 2);

cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);

comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null);
comboImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth() - (s.getWidth() / 2), c
        .getHeight()
        - (s.getHeight() / 2), null);
return cs;
```

}

It working good. But problem is that it make my image BLUR.

Basically my full code is here. [My Full Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133879/why-bitmap-to-base64-string-showing-black-background-on-webview-in-android)  What I am doing is converting my Base64 String images to Bitmap. What you think this may be issue?

I just want to prevent BLUR to my images...

Comment: oh yes, I just make the 3 images of hdpi,mdpi,ldpi "+" image. and it works for me.
Well you should not answer , but comment on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh yes, I just make the 3 images of hdpi,mdpi,ldpi "+" image with appropriate resolution. and it works for me.