# How to save canvas overlay bitmap in sd-card?

Tags: android

I am making an app in which I am drawing a bitmap on a canvas as a overlay after erasing some part of overlay bitmap I want to save it into sd-card but when is save it contain black
UI like attach screen[image]

And My code is bellow:-

```
public EraserView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
    // setting paint
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAlpha(0);
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Resources r = this.getContext().getResources();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.image2);
    bitmap = bm.createBitmap(295, 260, Config.ARGB_8888);
    pcanvas = new Canvas();
    pcanvas.setBitmap(bitmap); // drawXY will result on that Bitmap
    pcanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    pcanvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    setBitmap(bitmap);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
switch(event.getAction())
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();
        r = 2;
       invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();
        r = 20;
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();
        r =2;
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();
        r = 2;
        // Atlast invalidate canvas
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}
```

But My requirement is only save overlay thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When CompressFormat is *JPEG* its shows you black background because [JPEG format does not support alpha transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5133915/646806), just change  CompressFormat to *PNG* and even save your image in *png format* instead jpeg. check below code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream objbytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, objbytes);
```

While delcare path of image, use .png extension.

> directory + "/pics+"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";

Comment: Perhaps you didn't get question, My need is how to save only overlay bitmap ,currently bitmap is saving properly but with black background so kindly help regarding that..

Comment: Do you want to save the black part. Or the dog? Could you clarify what the foreground and what is the background is in your picture?

Comment: @Rvdk I want to save only dog part