# Why Bitmap showing black background in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I wrote some code witch can to convert tablelayout to bitmap.everythink working perfect but, my bitmap has black background
this is a my source code

```
public Bitmap sendMyData(TableLayout view) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    ByteArrayOutputStream bbb = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bbb);
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return bitmap;

}
```

what 's wrong in my code?why my bitmap has black background?
if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: below link may help you out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536066/convert-view-to-bitmap-on-android

Comment: try with Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG

Comment: @AMD , .PNG not working, still black background

Answer (score 11):

**JPEG** format must have background color.So when you convert **PNG** image or icon to **JPEG**, replace the **transparent background** with black color.

> convert it as PNG. bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
>   bbb);

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bbb, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: @Beka we don't have enough code to tell it for sure, but you must add Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 to one of the methods that load/convert/scale bitmap. It tells explicitly that bitmap is transparent.

Comment: what is this `bbb` parameter ?

Comment: @user889030 check in the question

Answer (score 3):

You may have already found the answer to this question but just for benefit of those who are still looking for the answer, here it is.

JPEG obviously gives far better compression and smaller image size than PNG. The small size is desirable in optimizing network, storage and image loading transactions. However when you save a view as JPEG the transparent background defaults to "black" colour. So if you want it to be any other colour (including white), you have to set the background of the view to that colour with the following code in the XML of your layout

```
android:background="@color/whiteColor"
```

And you have to define your color in colors.xml as below

```
    <color name="whiteColor">#FFFFFF</color>
```

This should help you achieve the desired compression along with the desired visuals. All the Best...

Answer (score 1):

I wish Android would have defaulted to a white background instead. Nevertheless, here's what we use to save PNGs with transparency as JPGs with a white background.

```
public static byte[] ConvertBitmapToJPGBytes(Bitmap img)
{
    img = ConvertTransparentBackgroundToWhite(img);
    if (img == null)
        return null;

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
    img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    img.recycle( );
    return stream.toByteArray( );
}

private static Bitmap ConvertTransparentBackgroundToWhite(Bitmap bm)
{
    if (bm == null)
        return null;
    if (bm.hasAlpha( ))
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth( ), bm.getHeight( ), bm.getConfig( ));
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);
            bm = newBitmap;
        }
        catch (RuntimeException exc)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return bm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JPEG format does not support alpha transparency, which is why the transparent background becomes black when you convert your original image to JPEG.

Use the PNG format instead

I found it Here : [Why Bitmap to Base64 String showing black background on webview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133879/why-bitmap-to-base64-string-showing-black-background-on-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

you should set *draw color* to white and your font color to *black*

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```