# Black background PNG file uploaded by converting Bitmap to String

Tags: php, android, bitmap

I Converted a **Bitmap** to **String** Format and posted it to **Server** via using **Volley library** .

This is `method` i used for convert **bitmap** to **string**:

```
 public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

I posted returned **String** value of this method to server , and in server side i get it by **PHP** :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["img"]))
{
    $image=$_POST["img"];

    $path="../uploads/1.png";

    file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
    echo "success";
}
?>
```

But the **background** of uploaded image (in **PNG** format) is **black color**.

how can i slove this problem  ?

---

this is real PNG:

[image]

and this is uploaded result :

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, but maybe you want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5133915/6386583). Not the JPEG part but maybe the imgTag part.

Comment: as you see , i uesd **CompressFormat** in PNG format before.in this line bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);